# `mhchem` vs `chemformula`

Tags: chemistry, mhchem, chemformula

Can you explain the main differences/advantages/disadvantages between `package` `mhchem` and `chemformula`? I don't mean the exact usage but the main aspects to choose between them (e.g. one of them is recommended for some specific field or one of them is more easy to use for the "basics" and other is for the more complex formulas).

I am writing now a longer paper with basic reagents and some oxidation/reduction equations but I can't decide between the two `packages` (without reading approx. one hundred pages of manual).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic overview over some key differences (not so many, actually):

|  | `mhchem` | `chemformula` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| developed by | Martin Hensel | Clemens Niederberger (i.e., me) |
| focuses on | ease of use and simplicity | customizability and extendability by the user |
| actively maintained | yes | yes |
| has rudimentory support for TeX4HT | yes | no |
| pgf/TikZ required | no | yes |
| can be used with `chemmacros` | yes | yes |
| is picky about input syntax | sometimes | always |
| can be recommended by me | yes | yes |

Which one you want to use in a matter of taste in the vast majority of use cases IMHO.  There might be edge cases when one can be preferred over the other.

Comment: Wrote you this table with LaTeX? I ask you, cause it's the type of table I like it.