# How do you write H2O in LaTeX

Tags: chemistry

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new in LaTeX, and have never used it for chemistry, just math.
How do you write water, `H2O`, in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `H\textsubscript{2}O`, though there are some packages devoted to chemical typesetting, if you intend to do a lot of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **mhchem**, too. And you can do more.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{H2O}

\vspace{1cm}

\ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do the same _more_ in `chemformula`, too, by the way... https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572013/

Answer (score 5):

With `chemformula`, you simply type

```
\ch{H2O}.
```

If you use `mhchem`, replace the `\ch` command with `\ce`.

Answer (score 4):

Using, for example, the `chemmacros` package for the chemical formula of the water.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\ch{H2O}
\end{document}
```

**Follow-up**: There is also `chemfig` package to write the formula of the water.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_2O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the documentation https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf here there is an example of reaction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemnameinit{\chemfig{R-C(-[:-30]OH)=[:30]O}}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{R’OH}}{Alcohol}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{R-C(-[:-30]OH)=[:30]O}}{Carboxylic acid}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemname{\chemfig{R-C(-[:-30]OR’)=[:30]O}}{Ester}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While `chemfig` is a great package it's really not for a simple formula like H₂O. It's for sceletal formulas and the like. Also, `chemmacros` does not provide `\ch`, `chemformula` does. The latter is loaded by `chemmacros` unless the user tells `chemmacros` to use `mhchem`.

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you very much for your explanation and I hope that I have not wrong something.